Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() but I can see the drivers when I use phpinfo
I am trying to connect a web UI to a SQL Server database. However, my web server cannot call the sqlsrv_connect() function with this error message:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in /var/www/localhost/htdocs/login.php:8 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/localhost/htdocs/login.php on line 8.

But when I run php -m I see the necessary drivers. In addition, the drivers are also displayed by phpinfo():
Additional .ini files parsed /etc/php83/conf.d/00_curl.ini, /etc/php83/conf.d/00_mbstring.ini, /etc/php83/conf.d/00_odbc. ini, /etc/php83/conf.d/00_opcache.ini, /etc/php83/conf.d/00_openssl.ini, /etc/php83/conf.d/00_pdo.ini, /etc/php83/conf.d/00_session. ini, /etc/php83/conf.d/00_xml.ini, /etc/php83/conf.d/01_mysqlnd.ini, /etc/php83/conf.d/01_pdo_sqlite.ini, /etc/php83/conf.d/02_mysqli. ini, /etc/php83/conf.d/02_pdo_mysql.ini, /etc/php83/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pdo_sqlsrv.ini, /etc/php83/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sqlsrv.ini 

I'm using this Docker Image: namoshek/php-mssql:8.3-cli-alpine
and added these commands to my Dockerfile:
FROM namoshek/php-mssql:8.3-cli-alpine

USER root

RUN docker-php-ext-install session
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache apache2 apache2-utils php php-apache2 php-mysqli php-pdo_mysql php-json php-opcache session.so

RUN apk add --no-cache unixodbc unixodbc-dev

RUN echo "extension=pdo_sqlsrv" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini \
  && echo "extension=sqlsrv" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

RUN echo "LoadModule php_module modules/libphp.so" >> /etc/apache2/httpd.conf \
  && echo "AddHandler php-script .php" >> /etc/apache2/httpd.conf \
  && echo "DirectoryIndex index.php index.html" >> /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "httpd -D FOREGROUND"]

BTW I'm using SQL Server 2022
Somehow, I still can't find a solution. PHP should know the function and be able to establish a connection to the SQL Server.

Command line php and webpage php don't get things from the same place; when you checked, where you getting the information from the same environment? Your error suggests a web page,  then you state you used php -m which is an entirely separate, command line, environment.

It seems that you are requesting a method/function from a location that has no access to it, you either follow PSR-4 standard or whatever you like as in MVC stands good practices or you can include the file that has that method where is needed.. <?php include_once 'db_conection.php'; $dbs = new SrvdbConections(); $query = $dbs->query("SELECT..... etc that inside of the file that is requesting that method/function, I'd recommend to follow PSR-4 or MVC standard for good practice.

it works now. for this i had to enter the same extension dir in the prod php.ini file, which is displayed with this command: php -i | grep extension_dir
Unfortunately, I have only made many changes in the dev php.ini so far. That's why it couldn't work at all. Thanks for the help
